# Only first character of field submitting from HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, salesforce

We have an HTML form which submits leads to Salesforce. I will paste the code below. I added some Javascript which allows me to have one name field instead of separate first and last name fields. It them submits anything after the first word in to the last name field.

However, when the user only submits one word in to the field, only the first character is submitted.

Eg. Name field in form = 'John', Name field in Salesforce = 'J'

```js
function TextCapture(txtid) {
  var OriginalValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
  document.getElementById("first_name").value = OriginalValue.substr(0, OriginalValue.indexOf(' '));
  document.getElementById("last_name").value = OriginalValue.substr(OriginalValue.indexOf(' '));;
}
```

```html
<body data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1
  data-rsssl=1>
  <div>
    <form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" target='_parent'>
      <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D0Y0000034cvq">
      <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://globalstudyuk.com/success">
      <br />
      <h5>
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" onchange="TextCapture(this)" type="text" />
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" />
        <input type="hidden" id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" />
```

Comment: If they don't type a space, `OriginalValue.indexOf(' ')` is `-1`. You need to check for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user inputs only one word, without any space `OriginalValue.indexOf(' ')` will return `-1`

Then `OriginalValue.substr(-1)` will return a portion of the string starting at the specified index and extending for a given number of characters afterward. Which means `-1` will be the last character of that word, `-2` will be last two characters and so forth.

Better way to solve this issue is to use split. That way even if there is only one word you have one split. Then given the number of splits you assign it to your first_name and last_name hidden inputs.

This will only work if user enters exactly two words (firstname, lastname), what if someone has a middle name? Or has more than three words? Consider international names, some people have ridiculous long names like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff_Sr.) `Hubert Blaine Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff Sr`

```
function TextCapture(txtid) {
  //var OriginalValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var OriginalValue = txtid.value; // You already have input passed from html
  document.getElementById("first_name").value = OriginalValue.split(' ').slice(0,1);
  document.getElementById("last_name").value = OriginalValue.split(' ').slice(1,2);
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt paste JUST code, you should explain why the OPs attempt did not work and what you did to resolve it. Beyond that you should try to use good standards when helping newbies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the name by a space character, try `split` Array method.

```js
function TextCapture(txtid) {
  var OriginalValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var valArr = OriginalValue.split(' ')
  document.getElementById("first_name").value = valArr[0] || ''
  document.getElementById("last_name").value = valArr[1] || ''

  console.log(valArr)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" target='_parent'><input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D0Y0000034cvq">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://globalstudyuk.com/success">
    <br />
    <h5>
      <label for="name">Full Name</label>
      <input id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" onchange="TextCapture(this)" type="text" /> <br />
      <input type="hidden" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" />
      <input type="hidden" id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" />
    </h5>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If they don't type two names, `valArr[1]` will be undefined.